# R download for Apple M3 chip

Tags: r, macos, hardware

I am exploring the purchase of an Apple MacBook Pro with an M3 chip and would want to install R on it.  When I go to https://cran.r-project.org/, however, I see only a reference to M1 and M2 chips.

A general search yields no clues as to whether this reference was made prior to the introduction of the M3 chip and not yet updated or whether there really is no option for loading R onto an M3 based machine.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: To my knowledge, it should work for all M-series chips because they use the same ARM-based architecture. Often they are comprehensively referred to as "Apple Silicon". Just make sure you don't get the Intel version (although for most normal programs those can be emulated).

Comment: Since "M1/M2" chips are specified on CRAN, rather than "Apple Silicon", it gave me pause.  I just needed somebody else's view; I'll give it a go and report back.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As M3 still is Apple Silicon, I think you should be good for installation of R.
https://rstudio.github.io/r-manuals/r-admin/Installing-R-under-macOS.html Also mentions the M3 chips:

> The first runs is for ‘Apple Silicon’ (aka ‘M1’, ‘M2’ or ‘M3’) Macs